# Is there a function or crate to display errors with line and column numbers, help text, and highlighting?

Tags: error-handling, rust

Rust has very clear error display, showing the line and part of line where an error occurred:

[image]

Is there a function from the Rust standard library or crate which replicates this for an arbitrary error? I'm kind of assuming it must exist somewhere within the Rust codebase, but can't find anything (mostly because any search term like "Rust rich line errors..." returns errors people have got while writing Rust, not how to generate the error display :-)).

E.g. I have the line number and character number of an error as well as the source, is an existing implementation of the above pretty error which I can reuse?

Comment: What's your use case?

Comment: giving line errors when parsing yaml, (I'm currently using `serde-yaml` to parse the content)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is of much help, but the `rustc` compiler uses the [rustc_errors](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/nightly-rustc/rustc_errors/index.html) crate to generate these messages. I found this by looking at the README in [librustc](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/tree/master/src) and searching the guide book for "message".

The search brought me to [this section](https://rust-lang.github.io/rustc-guide/diag.html?highlight=message#error-messages) in the guide which covers error messages.